# RavenDB StartsWith Variable on left-hand-side of Query

Tags: ravendb

I have a collection of docs with a Url property that looks like:

```
{ Url: www.test.com }  
{ Url: www.test.com/abc }  
{ Url: www.test.com/abc/xyz }
```

I want to query the docs with **www.test.com/abc** such that I am returned all the documents that match the url on everything **up-to-and-including** the query url. i.e. the results would return:

```
{ Url: www.test.com }  
{ Url: www.test.com/abc }
```

Below is the query I have written to accomplish this. As you can see, it relies on the 'Starts With' to be performed on the queryTerm, as opposed to being performed on a property of the document (the left-hand-side of the query).

```
var queryTerm = "www.test.com/abc";
pages = session.Query<MyDocument>()
               .Where(x => queryTerm.StartsWith(x.Url));
```

This does not work in Raven; I get an 'Expression type not supported' error. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't compare the indexed value to a variable, that would force us to do a table scan.

Comment: This is the point-blank answer I needed - we will use a different approach altogether. Just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Raven doesn't appear to support that in its expression. Interestingly, the query `x => queryTerm.StartsWith(x.Url)` can be exploded into something along the lines of:

```
x => x.Url == queryTerm ||
     x.Url == queryTerm.Remove(queryTerm.Length - 1) ||
     x.Url == queryTerm.Remove(queryTerm.Length - 2) ||
     x.Url == queryTerm.Remove(queryTerm.Length - 3) ||
     x.Url == queryTerm.Remove(queryTerm.Length - 4) ||
     etc.
```

Which can be codified as:

```
var terms = Enumerable.Range(0, queryTerm.Length)
                      .Skip(1)
                      .Select(i => queryTerm.Remove(i));

pages = session.Query<MyDocument>()
               .Where(x => terms.Contains(x.Url));
```

**Except** Raven doesn't supports `Contains()` like that either. So I coded this up:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Raven.Client;
using Raven.Client.Embedded;
using Raven.Client.Linq;

namespace RavenTest
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class HowToDoBackwardsStartsWithInRaven
    {
        private readonly string[] _testUrls = new[]
            {
                "www.bad.com",
                "www.test.com",
                "www.test.com/abc",
                "www.test.com/abc/xyz"
            };

        private readonly string _queryTerm = "www.test.com/abc";

        private readonly string[] _expectedResults = new[]
            {
                "www.test.com",
                "www.test.com/abc"
            };


        [Test]
        public void FailsWithContains()
        {
            List<MyDocument> results;

            using (var store = InitStore())
            {
                LoadTestData(store);

                using (var session = store.OpenSession())
                {
                    var terms = GetAllStartingSubstrings(_queryTerm);

                    results = session.Query<MyDocument>()
                        .Where(x => terms.Contains(x.Url))
                        .ToList();
                }
            }

            Assert.That(results.Select(p => p.Url), Is.EquivalentTo(_expectedResults));
        }

        [Test]
        public void SucceedsWithSuperWhere()
        {
            List<MyDocument> results;

            using (var store = InitStore())
            {
                LoadTestData(store);

                using (var session = store.OpenSession())
                {
                    var terms = GetAllStartingSubstrings(_queryTerm);

                    var query = session.Query<MyDocument>()
                        .Where(x => x.Url.Length <= _queryTerm.Length);

                    foreach (var term in terms)
                        query = query.Where(x => x.Url == term ||
                                                 x.Url.Length != term.Length);

                    results = query.ToList();
                }
            }

            Assert.That(results.Select(p => p.Url), Is.EquivalentTo(_expectedResults));
        }

        private static IDocumentStore InitStore()
        {
            var store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
                {
                    RunInMemory = true,
                };

            return store.Initialize();
        }

        private static string[] GetAllStartingSubstrings(string queryTerm)
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(0, queryTerm.Length)
                .Skip(1)
                .Select(i => queryTerm.Remove(i))
                .ToArray();
        }


        private void LoadTestData(IDocumentStore store)
        {
            using (var session = store.OpenSession())
            {
                foreach (var testUrl in _testUrls)
                    session.Store(new MyDocument {Url = testUrl});

                session.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public class MyDocument
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string Url { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Now... I have no idea how efficient the indexing will be on that but the test does pass.

Comment: Thanks Jim, this helps. I haven't marked it as the answer as we're not going to take this approach. Mostly because of the multiple querying that has to be done when looping through the starting substrings. This would be a problem if there were other urls in the database shorter than the queryTerm that would also have to be queried on within the loop. (Granted, in the interest of keeping the question short that detail was ommitted :-)

Comment: I don't understand that last part. Can you explain?

Comment: Just meant that I didn't specify in the question that the dataset might contain urls such as www.aaa.com or www.bbb.com which would need to be queried against if you returned all urls from the db with length shorter than the queryTerm...

Comment: Well yeah I expected that. You might not have noticed, but I added "www.bad.com" to the testUrls to verify the query doesn't return false matches.

Comment: Indeed you did, my bad. Its not that I expect such urls to be returned - just that there could be a lot of them to ignore.